# MacBook Air won't boot MacOS from new SSD but works with Ubuntu

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, startup, ssd, install

Losing my mind trying to problem solve this one. Have replaced an old SSD after it failed. Figured a new SSD would do the trick but after installing Mac OS on it and installing it in my MacBook all I get is a folder with a question mark. Disk utility won't load, connecting to online server just freezes. I've tried just about everything with no luck getting it to boot up, UNTIL I installed Ubuntu on the SSD using a bootable usb. Now my MacBook boots up fine. Have since tried re-installing a couple SSD's with Mac OS on them and had no luck. I figure it must be a software issue but can't for the life of me work out what. Any help would be awesome.
Cheers

Comment: where exactly do the install processes fail? What guide are you following to install macOS on the SSD?

Comment: It sounds like your order of operations is the culprit. Did you install macOS on the SSD and **THEN** put it in the Mac> If so you need to put it in the Mac *FIRST* and then boot into recovery mode to install macOS. The macOS install process for blank drives places a couple of small boot partitions on the SSD that are particular to that Mac that are *required* The days of installing macOS on any old drive and booting from it are going away.

Comment: If it's old enough to have an actual SSD, it's old enough to be able to boot from pretty much *any* drive, made anywhere… so long as it was made *correctly*, which is what we have yet to establish. Method details are important.

Comment: Which MacBook Air model? What version of macOS?